# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, date, datetime, datepicker

i use VB.NET On Visual Studio 2008

Error: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.**

**Code.**

```
    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length())
    sb.Append("SELECT tf.*")
    sb.Append(" FROM filesTA tf")
    sb.Append(" WHERE tf.ChkDate = '" & dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
    Dim SqlLR As String = sb.ToString()
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = SqlLR
    da.Fill(ds, "filesTA9")

    If ds.Tables("filesTA9").Rows.Count = 0 Then
        sb.Remove(0, sb.Length())
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO filesTA (EmpNo,ChkDate,LastUpdate) ")
        sb.Append("SELECT tft.EmpNo,tft.ChkDate,tft.LastUpdate ")
        sb.Append("FROM TA_FillTime tft ")
        sb.Append("WHERE Convert(nvarchar(10),tft.ChkDate,126) Between DATEADD(Day , -1, '" & dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' and '" & dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")
        sb.Append(" Order By tft.ChkDate ")

        Dim SqlLR2 As String = sb.ToString()
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = SqlLR2
        da.Fill(ds, "filesTA9") => **Error this line: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.**
        'label1.Text = "Insert Done"
    ElseIf ds.Tables("filesTA9").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'label1.Text = "Insert New Done"
    Else
        'label1.Text = "Insert Done..."
    End If
```

thanks you for your time. :)

Comment: That's an error in your SQL.  Use the debugger to read the actual command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a bracket:

```
  ..snip.. Between DATEADD(Day , -1, '" & dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & ")' and ...snip ...
  scroll over here--->                                                                   ^---here
```

which left you with an unterminated `DATEADD()` function call. Posting the code to generate an sql query is generally not as useful as showing the actual query you've generated. SQL syntax errors can be hard enough to spot without having to extract the query from a few tons of useless "fluff" around them.

Comment: thank very much!. i'm really forgot a bracket =_=